integrating IMU with a 3 wheel omni drive
I am trying to integrate an imu with my 3 wheel omni drive. Individually the imu yaw correction part works and individually the drive movement part works but for some reason which I am not able to identify the drive and imu arent working together can someone please help me. I am using a BNO055 imu and an arduino mega.
This is what I had come up with to drive the chassis. I am having problems integrating both the imu and drive correctly.Can someone please identify the issue and help me out. what i want the drive to do is basically it should move around front back left and right without changing its yaw. ensuring that the front is always facing forward while moving i thought this would also make it move straight.
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  fetch_data();
  compute3wheel();
  ps_print();
 
  double motorspeed;
  double speedFactorL = (rL/88+rR/88)/2;
  motorspeed = 255 * speedFactorL;
  motorspeed = constrain(motorspeed,0,120);
  parse_data(datain);
 
  uint8_t system, gryo, accel, mg = 0;
  myIMU.getCalibration(&system, &gryo, &accel, &mg);
 
  imu::Quaternion quat=myIMU.getQuat();
 
  q0=quat.w();
  q1=quat.x();
  q2=quat.y();
  q3=quat.z();
  yaw=-atan2(2*(q0*q3+q1*q2),1-2*(q2*q2+q3*q3))-pi/2;
  yaw = yaw * (180.0 / pi);
  Serial.print("YAW = ");
  Serial.print(yaw);
  compute();
  Serial.print("ERROR = ");
  Serial.println(yawerror);
 
  if(yawerror<0)
  {
      digitalWrite(motorfrontdir,LOW);
      target_wf+=output;
      digitalWrite(motorreardirr,HIGH);
      target_wrr+=output;
      digitalWrite(motorreardirl,LOW);
      target_wrl+=output;
      Serial.println(output);
  }
  else if(yawerror>0)
  {
      digitalWrite(motorfrontdir,HIGH);
      target_wf-=output;
      digitalWrite(motorreardirr,LOW);
      target_wrr-=output;
      digitalWrite(motorreardirl,HIGH);
      target_wrl-=output;
      Serial.println(output);    
  }
  applyDeceleration();
  delay(BNO055_SAMPLERATE_DELAY_MS);
}
 
void compute3wheel() {
 
  // Calculate joystick-based velocities
  double vx = ly;
  double vy = lx;
  w = rx;
  double speedFactorL = (rL/88+rR/88)/2;
 
  // Compute target angular velocities for each wheel
  target_wf = ((-0.5*vx) + (sqrt(3)/2)*vy + l0*w) * speedFactorL;
  target_wrr =((-0.5*vx)-(sqrt(3)/2)*vy + l0*w) * speedFactorL;
  target_wrl = (vx+l0*w) * speedFactorL;
  // Constrain target wheel speeds to PWM range
  target_wf = constrain(target_wf, -200, 200);
  target_wrr = constrain(target_wrr, -200, 200);
  target_wrl = constrain(target_wrl, -200, 200);
}
 
void applyDeceleration() {
  // Gradually approach target speeds for each wheel
  current_wf = target_wf;
  current_wrl = target_wrl;
  current_wrr = target_wrr;
  Serial.print("wf =");
  Serial.print(current_wf);
  Serial.print("wrr =");
  Serial.print(current_wrr);
  Serial.print("wrl =");
  Serial.println(current_wrl);
  // Update motor directions and speeds based on decelerated values
  if (current_wf >= 0) {
    digitalWrite(motorfrontdir, LOW);
    analogWrite(motorfrontpwm, current_wf);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(motorfrontdir, HIGH);
    analogWrite(motorfrontpwm, -current_wf);
  }
  if (current_wrl >= 0) {
    digitalWrite(motorreardirl, LOW);
    analogWrite(motorrearpwml, current_wrl);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(motorreardirl, HIGH);
    analogWrite(motorrearpwml, -current_wrl);
  }
 
  if (current_wrr >= 0) {
    digitalWrite(motorreardirr, HIGH);
    analogWrite(motorrearpwmr, current_wrr);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(motorreardirr, LOW);
    analogWrite(motorrearpwmr, -current_wrr);
  }
}
 

Individually the imu yaw correction part works and individually the drive movement part works but for some reason which I am not able to identify the drive and imu arent working together can someone please help me.Basically what i want is the drive to go straight forward backward left and right using an imu. Basically i dont want the yaw correction to fight with the controller inputs and i dont understand how to achieve that

You really should pick a MCU with on-board FPU for this project. Old 8 bit junk is entirely unsuitable for floating point math.
